# Ranking search results by counting words related via PDO/SQL

Tags: php, mysql, search, pdo, keyword

I would like to create a search engine that displays results by ranking preset. The rating consists of two parts 1. The amount of post views (represented by POP [INT] in "post" table) and the amount of the words in the text itself (represented by TXT [STRING] in "post" table).

**That is if there is a three-Results**

```
//$search = 'apple macbook';
```

1. 3 hits (POP) and 3 keywords related (2 MACBOOK, 1 APPLE found in TXT) = ***6*** - will be presented *first*
2. 2 hits (POP) and 3 keywords related (1 MACBOOK, 1 APPLE found in TXT) = ***5*** - will be presented *Second*
3. 2 hits (POP) and 1 keyword related (1 APPLE found in TXT) = ***3*** - will be presented *Third*

**My code:**

```
$search = isset($_GET['s']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['s']) : ''; 
$search = strtoupper($search);
$search = strip_tags($search); 
$search = trim($search);
$words = explode(' ', $search);
$words_condition = array();
$arguments = array();
foreach ($words as $word) {
    $words_condition[] = 'TXT LIKE ?';
    $arguments[] = '%'.$word.'%';
}

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE ".implode(" OR ",
    $words_condition)." ORDER BY POP DESC"); $query->execute($arguments);
```

About my table structure ("post" table) there are 4 Column...

1. ID [INT] 2. SUB (the subject of the post) [STRING] 3. TXT (the body/full text) [STRING] 4. POP [INT] (hits of visit this post).

Comment: Can you give us your table structure?

Comment: You are not using the prepared statements in  the correct way. By simply concatenating the search terms you are still vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: @Philipp thank you for your comment.. about my table structure ("post" table) there are 4 Column... 1. ID [INT] 2. SUB (the subject of the post) [STRING] 3. TXT (the body/full text)  [STRING] 4. POP  [INT] (hits of visit this post).

Comment: @philipp any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE post (id INT, txt varchar(100), pop int);
INSERT INTO post VALUES (1, "key key cle cle", 1);
INSERT INTO post VALUES (2, "key key cle cle", 2);
INSERT INTO post VALUES (3, "key key cle", 2);
INSERT INTO post VALUES (4, "key cle cle", 1);

SELECT *, (LENGTH(txt) - LENGTH(replace(txt, 'cle', '')))/LENGTH("cle") as cle, 
    (LENGTH(txt) - LENGTH(replace(txt, 'key', '')))/LENGTH("key") as key,
    (LENGTH(txt) - LENGTH(replace(txt, 'cle', '')))/LENGTH("cle")+(LENGTH(txt) - LENGTH(replace(txt, 'key', '')))/LENGTH("key") as nbKW
FROM post 
ORDER BY nbKW DESC, pop DESC;
```

OK I test it and it works really well ! You have to adapt it with you argument !

Comment: Hi.. thank for your new answer... the are 2 main problem... 1. What happend if some one search 5 or unlimited words? Your query will work just for 2 word. 2. What about sql injection (the words are coming from searching engine via GET method) TIA

Comment: You have to adapt it, with your foreach($word) complete the "select part" of the query.

Comment: But how?  I dont understand

Comment: For each keywords, you add in the select part (LENGTH(txt) - LENGTH(replace(txt, 'keyword[x]', '')))/LENGTH("'keyword[x]") as 'keyword[x],

Comment: And for nbKW, (LENGTH(txt) - LENGTH(replace(txt, 'keyword[x]', '')))/LENGTH("keyword[x]") +  (LENGTH(txt) - LENGTH(replace(txt, 'keyword[x+1]', '')))/LENGTH("keyword[x+1]") + .....

Comment: (LENGTH(txt) - LENGTH(replace(txt, 'keyword[x]', '')))/LENGTH("'keyword[x]") --> it give you the amount of keyword[x] in your txt